# no tab group defined for launch configuration type org.eclipse.ant

Tags: eclipse

I'm unable to add new ant builder. I'm getting following message with a dialog box:
"no tab group defined for launch configuration type org.eclipse.ant.AntLaunchConfigurationType".
[image: no tab group defined for launch configuration type org.eclipse.ant.AntLaunchConfigurationType]

Could you please let me know where I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like some problem in the `org.eclipse.ant.ui` plugin. Is there any more info in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory?

Comment: There is nothing related to org.eclipse.ant.ui or ant or configurationtype in .log

Answer (score 0):

This might happen when we try to download a software from Eclipse Marketplace and if the installation was not done properly. Please try to uninstall the `Ant` tool and install it again. Best practice is to restart the IDE and usually it will ask for that automatically after the installation.

P.S. : Also try to search for Eclipse Marketplace update, it might cause an issue sometimes.